# How to repair damage from vehicle swipe/scrape?

Tags: repair, garage, repainting, damage

I accidentally scraped the outside of my garage while backing out. See picture.

[image]
Anyone know 1) what material this is made of and 2) how to repair it?

I was able to get the paint off my front car bumper already.

Much appreciated.

Comment: That's pretty impressive to hit the outside trim but miss the inside piece, closest to the opening. Clever stunt driving!

Answer (score 6):

Looks like rough cut lumber to me. Scrape off the loose, hairy stuff, get a quart of color matched exterior paint, and paint the damaged areas.

Comment: Don't worry about the gouges....it'll have that nice rustic look.

Answer (score 3):

The material you are showing appears to be "rough-sawn cedar" boards which are available at just about any building supply retailer.  It's soft wood and easy to work with.

To fix this with new material:

1. Remove the existing boards.  The easiest way is to pull the nail with a nail puller and then pry the boards off.
2. Measure replacement boards and cut them to size.  Then prime and paint them to match.
3. Install the new boards in place of the old ones and be done with it.

If you want to just fix what's there you can leave the boards in place but there will be some damage visible.  Just do some light sanding to remove the splintered wood fibers which will stick out and make this more visible.  Then touch-up the paint with some matching color.  You will notice it because you are aware of what happened but I think in general it will not be that noticeable.

Comment: While a full replacement of the boards will do the trick, it's probably overkill for this minor damage.

Comment: Some folks are really picky about how things look.

Comment: That's true. You did get my +1.

Comment: My mom did this to her garage door and I just slapped some fresh paint on it.  That's the nice thing about rough sawn cedar, it's hard to tell damage from how it originally was.

Answer (score 1):

> what material this is made of?

Well, it's wood. Particularly rough-sawn cedar as identified by the answers before me.

> how to repair it?

Do you want it perfect or just "repaired"?

**Perfect**

Remove, replace, and paint new boards.

**Repaired**

Sand the gouges to remove any splinters. Don't sand it perfect or else the perfect spot will stick out like a sore thumb amongst the rough-sawn cedar.

Get your local hardware store to color-match the existing paint.

The color match will likely not be perfect so you'll probably end up re-painting everything that's red. On the plus side you will have paint readily available for next time this happens =)